# Signed cookies between subdomains on CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, cookies, amazon-cloudfront

Having trouble setting a cookie (subdomain to parent) in a CloudFront configuration:

1. S3 bucket serving a static site with a CloudFront distribution. CNAME: `example.com`
2. API Gateway API with a custom domain: `api.example.com`
3. S3 bucket with a CloudFront distribution with CNAME: `files.example.com`

The web application on `example.com` contacts a lambda proxy GET method on `api.example.com`. This function, among other things, returns headers with values generated by `AWS.CloudFront.Signer.getSignedCookies()`

```
{
    'Set-Cookie': `CloudFront-Expires=...; Domain=.example.com`,
    'SEt-Cookie': `CloudFront-Signature=...; Domain=.example.com`,
    'SET-Cookie': `CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id=...; Domain=.example.com`
}
```

These are being sent to the client with the response, but for some reason are not sent in GET requests to the S3 bucket on `files.example.com`.

I am not certain if the issue is with the cookies being *set* or being *sent*: By looking at the application tab in chrome dev tools it seems that the cookies aren't there. However, in the network tab the cookies are indeed being sent alongside requests to `api.example.com` (but not with requests to `files.example.com`).

As far as I can tell the configuration should work in terms of Domain cookie policy (the subdomain is attempting to set a cookie with a parent domain, under which is a different subdomain of the parent, that should receive the cookies). Any other immediate suspects for this sort of behaviour?

Comment: When you say they are not being sent in GET requests to the S3 bucket, what do you mean exactly? They are being sent to the CloudFront origin and it is not forwarding the cookies? What is the source of this information?

Comment: Just to be clear: Q1: Do the `Set-Cookie`s appear as response headers or part of the response body returned from your GET method? Q2: What `url` or `policy` did you specify for your `getSignedCookie()` options?

Comment: @SteveBuzonas I'm inspecting the requests sent through the network tab in chrome devtools. The cookies are not attached to the GET request to the API.
@KhalidT. the cookies appear as response headers. The URL I specify is `files.example.com/*`

Answer (score -1):

You want to use the cookie domain `.example.com` instead of `example.com`. The leading `.` allows subdomains to access the cookie as well.

You also need to ensure that the cookies are being forwarded to the origin in your CloudFront behavior.

Comment: You're absolutely right, the `.` was missing on the domain attribute. Unfortunately there is no change in behaviour so I simply added it to the question.

Comment: All modern browsers respect the newer specification [RFC 6265](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265), and will ignore any leading dot,

Comment: @blueCat do you have sources showing browser acceptance? The compatibility test tool indicates wide acceptance, but not total.